# autocomplete search box unresponsive

Tags: javascript, php, search, autocomplete, box

I made an autocomplete search box that suggests words from a mysql table column as i type but the problem is that it works only if i limit the sql query at approx 1200...and i have about 2500 records. After 1200 it becomes unresponsive. I indexed the column as FULLTEXT and here is the code i use:

The HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var availableTags = <?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>;
                $("#furnizor").autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags,
                    autoFocus:true
                });
            });
      </script>
<input id="furnizor" type="text" size="50" />
```

And here is the php script 'autocomplete.php':

```
<?php 
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $sql1 = "select distinct name from search";
    $result_search = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $dname_list = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_search))
    {
        $dname_list[] = $row['name'];
    }
    echo json_encode($dname_list);
?>
```

The table is named 'search' and the column i search in is named 'name'.
So all this works if i limit the sql query to 1200...everything over that number becomes unresponsive.

Is there a way to make this work for about 2500 records?

Comment: Well, I guess the problem could be from autocomplete building the dom, so you could build the dom yourself and try to filter it, or use the ajax autocomplete way (like do an ajax request when the user types and limit it to somewhere around 10-20 rows)

Comment: I had the same issue however when using an Ajax call, and then I increased the  `post_max_size` and it worked for me... or maybe you have some encoding issues by some of your rows ...

Comment: Reducing the total number of items to be populated on the list is the key. One way is to use a `minLength` option. This will reduce the list massively while you type. Work out the suitable number for your application, between 3 - 6 sounds friendly to user.

Comment: I tried adding minLength: 3 and delay: 500 for autocomplete options but it's weird because it didn't increase my search limit at all...it still doesn't work above 1200.